# Json response being modified by unknown source between Php Laravel on Nginx server and angular page receiving it

Tags: php, angular, laravel, nginx

I make an api call to the server, but the json response is getting the below json appended to the front of it.  Which makes it invalid json and hence the api call fails when it tries to decode the json.  I can work around this by accepting plain text instead, but I would like to get to the bottom of the mystery.

{
"id": 2510744,
"status": "queued"
}

I cannot find what is doing this and have spent many hours trying to hunt down the source.  Interestingly it only happens on one API call all others are fine.  The others are after the user is logged in.

The flow is

- api call from client to create a new user (correct)
- php / lavarel backend adds new user to mySql db. (correct)
- new user is returned in json format. (correct up to terminate method in middleware)
- client receives response but it has the extra json block appended to the front.

So far I have:

- validated that the response is correct on the server.  I have added Laravel middleware terminate method to check what response is sent back, this is correct.  So the problem is after this point which also cancels out my php code and the mysql db.
- checked all logs but there is no mention.
- considered if it is something to do with php-fpm, but after looking at the config and logs can find nothing which would do this.
- looked at the Nginx config, this has a couple of modules loaded which I think could modify the response, but I can't see anything in the config where they are used.  These are:
  :ngx_http_image_filter_module
  :ngx_http_xslt_filter_module.so
- I also commented these out of the config and reloaded Nginx and the problem was still there.
- called the same api from a react app and get the same modified response so it seems unlikely that it is on the client side.
- called the api from reqbin and got the same response, so it definitely isn't client side.

So far I have not managed to get Nginx to log the response content.  I have found posts online how to do this but they are quite old and I thought I would ask here first.

Hopefully this is an obvious problem to someone because I don't know what else to try.  Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: one of your middlewares involved with the client call for the api has an `echo()` or a `dump()`

Comment: Try `egrep 'echo|dump|dd' app/*` from your command-line, and see if you can track down where the code is.

Comment: I have searched on those now and id and status, but no luck.

Comment: Oh, I forgot the recursive tag on the command, otherwise it's only going to search that first level. `egrep -R 'echo|dump|dd' app/*`

Comment: Ok, so I am getting nearer.  Your comments got me thinking that it might be something in the code dumping data.  So I put in a return into the code and kept moving it to see at what point the json gets introduced.  After a bit of experimentation I have pinned it down to a single line.  $output = curl_exec($ch);  This is outputing the extra json.  So far I have tried adding  curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, false);  but this didn't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The extra json that was modifying my response was coming from

$output = curl_exec($ch)

It was outputting to stdout instead of returning the value to my $output variable.

To fix the issue I need to  add

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

This makes curl return the data instead of sending it to stdout.